# Recording voice note is not working on IOS using ionic media plugin

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, firebase-storage

I'm trying to record voice note on ios device using ionic cordova **Media** and **File** plugin and pushing it to firebase storage.

> On android is working well.

This is my **code**:

*First I created the `init()` function*

```
  init(): Promise < any > {
    this.date = moment().format('x');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let currentFile: File;
      this.fileName = this.date + `-rnb.mp3`;
      this.file.createFile(this.platform.is('ios') ? cordova.file.tempDirectory : cordova.file.dataDirectory, this.fileName, true).then((result) => {
        this.current_file_playing = this.createAudioFile(this.storageDirectory, this.fileName);
        resolve();
      }, (e) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
        reject(e);
      })
    });
  }
```

*`this.storageDirectory` it's a variable defined in the provider `constructor()` equal to directory path depends on the platform. and this is the following code:*

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.storageDirectory = this.file.tempDirectory;
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.storageDirectory = this.file.externalDataDirectory;
  }
});
```

*Then the `record()` function is listener to record button*

```
  record(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      this.init().then((media:Media) => {
        try {
          this.startRecording(media);
          resolve(media);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

*This is the `startRecording()` function:*

```
  startRecording(mediaPlugin: any) {
    this.current_file_playing.startRecord();
  }
```

*Moreover `stopRecording()` function is a listener to stop button:*

```
  stopRecording(mediaPlugin: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      this.current_file_playing.stopRecord();
      this.current_file_playing.play();
      this.current_file_playing.setVolume(0.0); //trick
      this.saveFirebase().then((downloadUrl) => {
        resolve(downloadUrl);
      });
    });
  }
```

*And Finally this is how I'm pushing  to firebase, using `saveFirebase()` function*

```
  saveFirebase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let metadata = {
        contentType: 'audio/mp3',
      };
      this.file.readAsDataURL(this.storageDirectory, this.fileName).then((file) => {
        let voiceRef = storageRef.child(`voices/${this.fileName}`).putString(file, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL);
        voiceRef.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, (snapshot) => {
          console.log("uploading");
        }, (e) => {
          console.log('inside the error');
          reject(e);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2),'this.error');
        }, () => {
          var downloadURL = voiceRef.snapshot.downloadURL;
          resolve(downloadURL);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

*Explanation of `saveFirebase()` function*

First I transformed the file to **base64** using `this.file.readAsDataURL(...)` then I pushed the Firebase Storage using `putString` method.

> The audio file is successfully pushed to Firebase Storage, But with 0 Byte size. That is mean to pushing to Firebase is working well, but the recording voice to the file is not working.

[image: This is my Firebase Storage]

> The audio files that have size is recorded from  android device.

Anyone have an idea what is my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you include the createAudioFile method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

The audio file should be **.wav**. So when I changed the type of audio to became wav.

```
  let metadata = {
    contentType: 'audio/wav',
  };

this.fileName = this.date + `-rnb.mp3`;
```

It work for me.

Thanks.